# Does raising warnings in JavascriptCore at compile time have significant startup overhead?

Tags: javascript, react-native, compiler-warnings, v8, javascriptcore

I have a complicated problem with a race condition in React Native. Does raising warnings at compile time significantly impact the initialisation tme of the javascript bundle?

The javascript bundle is a 130,000 line file and I suspect the side effects of printing the warnings to console (which is polyfilly in RN) before the script begins executing is wasting precious milliseconds. I can't find any explicit documentation on this for either V8 or Javascript Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to find a reliable answer to this question is to measure the effect yourself. Just compare how startup times of your app change with and without warnings.

If you would like some guesswork: Raising a single warning is probably negligible, raising tens of thousands of them probably causes noticeable slowdown. (My browser can do about 20,000 `console.log` calls per second, but of course a polyfill could be very different, both faster or slower.)